# Is there a Tool to View Disk Usage on a Team Foundation Server DB

Tags: sql-server, tfs, database, disk-access

We have a TFS installation on a machine that is close to going out of support life and we're planning on migrating to a new machine in a couple of months.  However in the meantime we are getting really low on disk space and (for whatever reason) we can't add more disk space.  This has me wondering if there is a tool that would show us how the DB is using the disk space which might help us identify some stuff we could delete/destroy to temporarily give us some more free space.

Comment: if you delete anything, make sure to run a shrink operation to reclaim the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_helpdb 'database' will show your mdf and ldf file sizes.  xp_fixeddrives will show free space.  May not be exactly what you are seeking but it is a starting point.

Comment: Yikes - turns out the DB is relatively small but the transaction log is huge - 670 GB!

Comment: Where do I type those commands? so far I have only used the TFS Administration Console. tks.